# can Java String function indexOf() look for multiple characters?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to reduce the runtime of a program I'm working on and I want to figure out a simpler way to find the index of a character with an integer value.

At the moment, my function traces through each character of a string and returns the **index** of the first integer it finds. As an example, if I had the string `JohnCena1237728394712` (yes, that's the first string I thought of), the function should return 8 because the first integer that occurs in the string, 1, is at index 8. It must first loop through each character before it to find that index, however, and that gets expensive at times.

If it helps when trying to think of an easier way to do this, I can be sure going in to the function that the format of the string will always be "[letters]" + "[numbers]" so I simply have to find the end of the (presumably random) segment of letters to get what I want.

What I would like to do is use indexOf() so I won't have to use a loop, but I do not know a way to use the function without having ten if statements (which, of course, would defeat the purpose).

Is there a way to check for multiple integers at once while using indexOf(), or some other function?

Comment: You could use a regex i.e, `matches()` . Can you show us sample input and output?

Comment: `indexOf()` will use a loop, so if you're concerned about algorithmic complexity, be careful.

Comment: As TheLostMind said, if you want to find the indexes of multiple characters, a `Pattern` and `Matcher` will give you that.

Comment: Your worst case efficiency will be `O(n)` no matter what approach you use. You will have to loop through each char one-by-one

Comment: hard to do faster than a character loop O(n), unless you know something about the strings that helps you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a regex matcher.

Something like:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
 if(matcher.find()) {
     return matcher.first();
 }
 return -1;
```

This is fairly readable and extensible. Some might consider it overkill compared to a simple `for` loop through the string. Compiling the regex takes time, and you have a couple of objects created, and all this costs if you're being fanatical about performance.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
     char c = str.charAt(i);
     if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
         return i;
     }
 }
 return -1;
```

Necessary, something will have to look at each character in turn, so there will be a loop somewhere, whether you write it or whether it's in the library method you call.

You might be able to squeeze some speed out of multiple cores by breaking the String into chunks and doing something map-reduce-ish. But this would only be worthwhile for really huge strings in which the digits were rare.

Comment: The OP asked for *speed* :). *"however, and that gets expensive at times."*. Also, it should be `\\d`

Comment: I think this is about as close as I'm going to get to speeding this up. The general consensus seems to be that my function is almost as good as it's going to get, since the single loop would run in linear runtime and indexOf() would run at the same rate.

Comment: @remingtonhowell Just a small correction: A single `indexOf()` would run at the same rate. But since that only checks a match for one char/string at a time, and you need to check for any digits (as far as your question specifies), then you'd need to run it multiple times (10), while the loops with `charAt()` (or similar without; see my answer) can check a character against the whole digits range, and thus only need to run once. --- There is a significant difference in speed (and redundancy) between these two approaches.

Comment: `str.length` needs parentheses in the second example: `str.length()`

Comment: If you want to go faster, you can help the JIT by only calling `str.length()` a single time before the loop starts.

Answer (score 1):

The way is to use the Regular Expression, that's a very powerful way to represent the string content..

```
String str = "Hello world";
str.matches("\\w+ \\w+");                   // returns true
```

And the example of using the classes `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

```
String line = "Hello amazing world";
String pattern = "(\\w+) \\w+ (\\w+)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println(m.group(1));        // Prints "Hello"
     System.out.println(m.group(2));        // Prints "world"
}
```

Comment: Looping will be faster than regex

Comment: Can you explain *what at* and *why* a loop would be ineffective? Considering the info we have, which is that the OP wants indexes of occurrences of a specific character in a String, a loop through the chars which gets their indexes seems to be exactly what he needs... And a Regex would needlessly entail a lot more (unused) features and their respective overheads...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ascii of the characters to see if it's an integer or no

Note: Assuming the interger is only 1 digit

```
String str = "hello123";
for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
         // Code goes here
    }
}
```

Alternative solutions:

- Use indexOf() for each target character, but this will have a time complexity of O(n^2)
- Store the set of target integers in a set, then loop on the string and check if the characters are in the set (This is good if the integer is more than one digit)

Comment: That's already what I'm doing. I want to think of a solution that does not involve a loop.

Comment: @remingtonhowell *Why* not use a loop? It will be pretty much inevitable that *some* loop will be used; either by you, or internally by the API...

Comment: Well, less code does not mean better performance ... @remingtonhowell

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid `.charAt(i)`, although there isn't much point to it... Simply get an array of `char` from the string, and loop though that with an indexed `FOR` loop that returns the index upon reaching the first digit:

```
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
for (int i=0; i<chars.lenght; i++) {
    if(chars[i] >= '0' && chars[i] <= '9')
        return i; //Or whatever code you need.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have a bunch of characters followed by a bunch of integers.

You can use a modified [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the point in the string where the transition occurs.  This should prove useful if you need to analyze very large strings.  Worst case performance is O(log n).

I've coded up an example below:

```
public class binSearch {

    static int indexFinder(String s) {

        // this doesn't check for invalid inputs btw
        int beg = 0;
        int end = s.length() - 1;
        int mid;
        int iter = 0;
        while (beg < end) {
            System.out.println("Iteration: " + iter + "   String: " + s.substring(beg, end+1));
            mid = (end + beg) / 2;
            System.out.println("Mid: " + mid + "   char: " + s.charAt(mid));
            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(mid))) {
                if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(beg))) {
                    return beg;
                }
                end = mid;
            } else {
                beg = mid + 1;
            }
            iter++;
        }
        return beg;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running");
        String[] strings = {"joohhhnnnnnCEEENNAAAAAA123829898", "efi1029082198"};

        for (String s : strings) {
            StringBuilder check = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                check.append(i % 10);
            }
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println(check.toString() + "\n");
            System.out.println("First int index: " + indexFinder(s) + "\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Running
joohhhnnnnnCEEENNAAAAAA123829898
01234567890123456789012345678901

Iteration: 0   String: joohhhnnnnnCEEENNAAAAAA123829898
Mid: 15   char: N
Iteration: 1   String: NAAAAAA123829898
Mid: 23   char: 1
Iteration: 2   String: NAAAAAA1
Mid: 19   char: A
Iteration: 3   String: AAA1
Mid: 21   char: A
Iteration: 4   String: A1
Mid: 22   char: A
First int index: 23


efi1029082198
0123456789012

Iteration: 0   String: efi1029082198
Mid: 6   char: 9
Iteration: 1   String: efi1029
Mid: 3   char: 1
Iteration: 2   String: efi1
Mid: 1   char: f
Iteration: 3   String: i1
Mid: 2   char: i
First int index: 3
```